# jQuery.click  и ссылки

Tags: jquery, html

Есть ссылка:

```
<a id="u-m" href="/?do=login" title="Войти на сайт"><div class="s_h"></div>Войти на сайт</a>
```

Если использовать [jQuery.click](http://api.jquery.com/click):

```
$('#u-m').click(function(){
    if(!$('#u-m').hasClass('select')){
        $('<div>',{class:"s"}).appendTo(this);
        $('#u-i').slideDown(100);
        $(this).toggleClass('select').find('.s_h').toggleClass("close");
    } else {
        $('#u-i').slideUp(100, function(){
            $('div.s').remove();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('select').find('.s_h').toggleClass("close");
    }
    return false;
})
```

то Safari на Mac открывает ссылку, хотя все другие обрабатывают код нормально.

Comment: Какие версии у JQuery и Safari? Как работает демо с сайта JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), если кнопку (button) поменять на ссылку (a) на Mac Safari?

Comment: jQuery: 1.4.4
Safari: 5.0.3
Ваш код в сафари работает, если для ссылки задать значение href="" то перестает работать, но лечиться return false;

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что сейчас проблема в том, что клик по <a href="" onclick="return false;">ссылка</a> вызывает переход на страницу на Маке?

Comment: Вот именно что если использовать только onclick="return false;" или

('#u-m').click(function(){
    return false;
}) 

то перехода нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, ошибка таилась вот здесь:

```
$('<div>',{class:"s"}).appendTo(this);
```

нужно использовать кавычки для атрибутов, правильно:

```
$('<div>',{'class':'s'}).appendTo(this);
```

Comment: Это потому что некоторые браузеры считают некоторые слова ключевыми. Вот, например, class. Все ключи в кавычках писать не нужно.

Comment: Но, тем не менее, всё же, разумно.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте этот код на Маке:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a>Toggle</a>
    <p>Привет</p>
    <p style="display: none">Пока</p>
    <script>
        $("a").click(function () {
            $("p").toggle();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Если не работает, то это баг в JQuery и нужно искать замену для toggle. Если работает, нужно удалить все лишнее из Вашей страницы и посмотреть, где ломается.